# Rendering DynamicFolderBundle?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I'm trying to add a bundled folder so I don't have to manually add each new .less file to the usual bundles,  but I don't know how to render it out.

In the BundleConfig,

```
 BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new DynamicFolderBundle("Content/autobundled", "*.less", new LessTransform(), new CssMinify()));
//.less sheets are at Content/autobundled/example.less
```

In the Razor page:

```
 @Styles.Render("Content/autobundled")
```

Output:

```
<link href="/Binky.Web/Content/autobundled" rel="stylesheet">
```

But that doesn't link any files, just links to the directory which isn't browsable. The articles I read don't say anything about how to use the folder bundles after you create them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Found the answer here](http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2012/09/03/using-asp-net-bundling-and-minification-with-less-files/)

Basically create the bundle, where the first parameter is the name (not the path) for the bundle,

```
bundles.Add(new DynamicFolderBundle("less", "*.less", new LessMinify()));
```

And render them by choosing a path, and use the bundle name appended to the path to say, "get all the files specified in this named bundle from this path".

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/autobundled/less")
```

Comment: I'm also using it  : `bundles.Add(new DynamicFolderBundle("userScripts", "*.js",new JsMinify()).Include("~/Scripts/YGeneral.js").Include("~/Scripts/ZGeneral.js"))` .But for some reason first it puts the script from the `DynamicFolderBundle` output , and THEN it puts the other `Includes`. How can I first put the `Includes` and THEN the `DynamicFolderBundle` ?